# \citep gives me only the first author author

Tags: citing, bibentry

If I use `\citep{}` I get

> (Hugh et al., 2009)

. However, I need

> (Hugh Glaser, Afraz Jafri, and Ian Millard, 2009)

```
  \begin{document}
  \usepackage{bibentry}

  \end{document}
```

I do not know how to execute the [bibentry](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibentry) package.

Comment: I think a good starting point will be to load any package before `\begin{document}`. Your question is more or less not usable. Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: The command `\citep*` will force the inclusion of the surnames (but not first names) of all authors in the citation callout.

Comment: @Mico I already tried \citep*, however nothing changed

Answer (score 3):

## `biblatex`

Use `\parencite` instead of `\citep`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{eps267587,
       booktitle = {WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)},
           month = {April},
           title = {Managing Co-reference on the Semantic Web},
          author = {Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jaffri and Ian Millard},
            year = {2009},
            note = { Event Dates: 20 April 2009},
        keywords = {Co-reference, Linked Data, Semantic Web},
             url = {http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/267587/}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{eps267587}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## `natbib`

Based on Mico's comment to use `\citep*` instead of `\citep`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{eps267587,
       booktitle = {WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)},
           month = {April},
           title = {Managing Co-reference on the Semantic Web},
          author = {Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jaffri and Ian Millard},
            year = {2009},
            note = { Event Dates: 20 April 2009},
        keywords = {Co-reference, Linked Data, Semantic Web},
             url = {http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/267587/}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citep*{eps267587}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: In the second (natbib/bibtex-based) example, one can generate round parentheses by specifying the option `round` when loading `natbib`. You may also want to explain explicitly, for the benefit of the uninitiated user, two key differences between the output generated by biblatex's `authoryear` style and bibtex's `plainnat` style: (i) Title style versus sentence style for the contents of the `title` field, and (ii) placement of the first author's given name either after or before the last name.